# Factory and controller, unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've got a controller made and I'm trying to move the data that is currently in it (was there for testing) out of the controller and im creating a factory so I can do api calls and such for the data when I get around to it.

I'm new to using both AngularJS and ionic an im not sure where the issue lies.

I'm currently getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: BookingHistoryFctryProvider <- BookingHistoryFctry <- BookingsHistoryCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/unpr?p0=BookingHistoryFctryProvider%20%3C-%20BookingHistoryFctry%20%3C-%20BookingsHistoryCtrl
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7888:12
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11806:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11953:39)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11811:45
    at getService (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11953:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11985:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12002:27)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16255:28
    at chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:622:22
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:40562:28 <div ui-view="">
```

My factory

```
    gomo_factories.factory('BookingsHistoryFctry', [ function(){
    return function BookingsHistoryFctry(){
        history : [
                { id: 1, date: '17 SEP', time: '14:30' , to: '24 Parramatta Road Leichardt' , from:'34 Enmore road Newtown' , type:'PASSENGER' },
                { id: 2, date: '17 SEP', time: '15:30' , to: '24 Parramatta Road Leichardt' , from:'34 Enmore road Newtown' , type:'DRIVER' },
                { id: 3, date: '17 SEP', time: '16:30' , to: '24 Parramatta Road Leichardt' , from:'34 Enmore road Newtown' , type:'PASSENGER' },
            ]
    };
}]);
```

My controller

```
    gomo_controllers.controller('BookingsHistoryCtrl',["$scope","BookingHistoryFctry", function($scope, BookingHistoryFctry) {


    /*$scope.history = [
        { id: 1, date: '17 SEP', time: '14:30' , to: '24 Parramatta Road Leichardt' , from:'34 Enmore road Newtown' , type:'PASSENGER' },
        { id: 2, date: '17 SEP', time: '15:30' , to: '24 Parramatta Road Leichardt' , from:'34 Enmore road Newtown' , type:'DRIVER' },
        { id: 3, date: '17 SEP', time: '16:30' , to: '24 Parramatta Road Leichardt' , from:'34 Enmore road Newtown' , type:'PASSENGER' },
    ];*/

    $scope.history = BookingHistoryFctry.history;

}]);
```

The controllers and factories are included in he index.html

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  var gomo; // Gomo Application
  var gomo_controllers = angular.module('gomo.controllers', ['ngCordova']); // Gomo Controllers
  var gomo_factories = angular.module('gomo.factories', ['ngCordova']); // Gomo Factories
</script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Factories -->
<script src="js/factories/bookingsHistoryFctry.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/bookingsHistoryCtrl.js"></script>
```

And their defined in the angular.module from the base app.js

```
gomo = angular.module('gomo', ['ionic', 'gomo.factories', 'gomo.controllers']);
```

Comment: you have a typo in the name of the factory, compare both. in your controller you wrote `BookingHistoryFctry` it should be `BookingsHistoryFctry`

Comment: and this is why more eyes are awsome when youve been looking at something for ages :D embarising, but it happens. Thanks mate time to get to work on making it work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your factory may be off. I might try:

```
gomo_factories.factory('BookingsHistoryFctry', ['$http', function($http){

      var booking = {};

      booking.history = function() {
            var history = [
                    { id: 1, date: '17 SEP', time: '14:30' , to: '24 Parramatta Road Leichardt' , from:'34 Enmore road Newtown' , type:'PASSENGER' },
                    { id: 2, date: '17 SEP', time: '15:30' , to: '24 Parramatta Road Leichardt' , from:'34 Enmore road Newtown' , type:'DRIVER' },
                    { id: 3, date: '17 SEP', time: '16:30' , to: '24 Parramatta Road Leichardt' , from:'34 Enmore road Newtown' , type:'PASSENGER' },
                ];

            return history;

      }

      return booking;


}]);
```

and then in your controller something like:

```
$scope.history = BookingsHistoryFctry.booking.history();
```